# set palette color range

Tags: gnuplot, palette

```
plot 'a.data' using 1:2:3 w p pt 7 ps 2 lc palette
```

plots points with colors in the palette, but the color values in the palette automatically range from 0.75 to 0.95 in my case. I would like to set a fixed color range of palette, say from 0 to 1. So how to do it?
Thanks!

Comment: ok. thanks.  (Comments must be at least 15 characters in length)

Answer (score 1):

The color range is controllable with `set cbrange`:

```
set cbrange [0:1]
```